# Automatically adding author's name before a reference, when natbib is not available

Tags: citing, journal-publishing

I am writing a paper with [this style file](http://sis.smu.edu.sg/sites/default/files/sis/conference/aamas2016/paper-submission/aamas2016_example.zip). It requires to use the "abbrv" bibliography style, and does not allow to use natbib.

When I cite a reference using \cite:

> \cite{Steinhaus1948} proved that...

It looks like this:

> [1] proved that...

The reviewers usually don't like it and they require to add the author's name, e.g:

> Steinhaus [1] proved that...

Normally, I would use \citep or \citet for this, but here they are not available.

Is there another way to automatically add the author's name before the  number?

Comment: Starting on line ca. 1200, the document class file (`aamas2016`) appears to provide a whole raft of citation commands (in addition to plain old `\cite`): `\citeNP`, `\citeA`, `\citeANP`, `\shortcite`, `\shortciteN`, `\shortciteA`, `\shortciteANP, `\citeyear`, `\citeyearNP`, plus probably a few more I've missed. Have you tried them out?

Comment: I perused the document class file some more -- does it ever contain a lot of cruft, including some duplicate and mutually inconsistent macro definitions (see, e.g., of `\@makecaption`). Be prepared for some strange and unexpected behavior!

Comment: @Mico the NP version seems to remove the parentheses (1 instead of [1]). The other variants apparently have no effect (maybe I don't know how to use them).

Comment: You may be stuck with having to write `Steinhaus~\cite{Steinhaus1948}`. :-(

Comment: @Mico isn't it possible to somehow duplicate the behavior of the "\citet" of natbib, using a \newcommand inside my document?

Comment: A huge obstacle lies in the fact that `abbrv` must be used. The `abbrv` bibliography style, being among the most ancient of all BibTeX style files, is really only meant for numerical citation call-outs. If only you were allowed to use `abbrvnat`, which can produce both numerical and authoryear-style citation call-outs.

Comment: If I use abbrvnat, is it possible to create the reference inside the text in the format "author [number]", while keeping the bibliography list as it is (with numbers)?

Comment: I'm afraid I can not figure out how to get `abbrvnat` to generate the required call-out format. :-(